# Moving boxes not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

My problem is that the plugin Moving Boxes does not work as it should. Here is the entire HTML. I have a lot of jQuery here and I don't know how to isolate all the plugins that I'm using.

I've tried to separate all the plugins but it does not seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Mobila</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.floatobject-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="CaractereDoublet_Limited_Version_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.easing.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.movingboxes.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="movingboxes.css" type="text/css" media="screen">       

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            Cufon.replace('.ui-accordion-header a', {
    hover: true,
    textShadow: '#555555 -1px 1px, #555555 2px 2px'
});});



        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ autoHeight: true,
                                    collapsible: true});
    });});
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){

$('#xxx').movingBoxes({

width : 800 // overall width of movingBoxes (not including navigation arrows)
});

});
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 10, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        pauseOnHover: true

    });
});});

</script>


</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).ready(main);

        function main()

        {

            $("#first").makeFloat({x:"current",y:"current",});

        }       
});
    </script>





<div id="first">


<a class="social" href="#"><img src="1728669589.png" width="64" height="64" /></a>
<a class="social" href="#"><img src="Google-Plus-Logo-Icon.png" width="64" height="64" /></a>


</div><!--end first-->


<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div><!--logo end-->
  <div id="slider1">


<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">

    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/106535379/Kitchens_Furniture_Cabinets.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/106535388/Kitchens_Furniture_Cabinets.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.floridamarkt.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Modern-Daybed-Design-for-Home-Outdoor-Furniture-Sculptural-Collection-by-Neoteric-Luxury-Twin.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://sunshineinteriors.net/images/content/pf/fur5_large.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>


</div><!--slider1 end-->
<br />
<div id="content">

<div id="demo">

<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Despre noi!</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Produse</a></h3>



    <div>
        <ul id="xxx">

<li>
<img src="http://www.flickr.com/photos/justbcuz/112479862g" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/justbcuz/112479862">more</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<img src="2698975899_430bd38aa6_o.jpg" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2698975899">more</a> and a whole lot more text goes here, so we can see the height adjust.</p>
</li>

<li>
<img src="http://flickr.com/photos/ruudvanleeuwen/468309897" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/ruudvanleeuwen/468309897">more</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<img src="http://flickr.com/photos/emikohime/294092478" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/emikohime/294092478">more</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<img src="http://www.flickr.com/photos/fensterbme/499006584" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/fensterbme/499006584">more</a></p>
</li>

<li>
<img src="demo/6.jpg" alt="picture">
<h2>News Heading</h2>
<p>Add a short exerpt here... <a href="#">more</a></p>
</li>

</ul> <!-- end Slider #1 -->
    </div>



    <h3><a href="#">Proiecte</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Contact</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div><!--end demo-->
</div><!--end content-->

<!--<div id="grafic"></div>-->



</div><!--wrapper end-->
</div>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
<![endif]-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
$('.first li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({rotate: '+45deg'});

$('.first li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({rotate: '0deg'});});

});</script>-->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to do a better job explaining what _"does not work as it should"_ is supposed to mean.  Don't make the reader guess.  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I have a lot of jQuery here and I don't know how to isolate all the plugins that I'm using."*

1. **Only use *one* $(document).ready() call**
2. **You want to move those jQuery calls into another file**, for example script.js

==script.js==

A simple way to organize your handlers coud be:

```
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {

    doMoveHandler: function() {
        $("#movingdiv").click(function() {
             // code moving div
        });
    },
    doJumpHandler: function() {
      // code here
    },
    doCufonHandler: function() {
        Cufon.replace('.ui-accordion-header a', {
            hover: true,
            textShadow: '#555555 -1px 1px, #555555 2px 2px'
        });

    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // If something doesn't work comment out
    // other functions rest to debug that specific plugin!
    // mynamespace.doMoveHandler();
    mynamespace.doJumpHandler();

    mynamespace.doCufonHandler();
}
```

A better way is to use a full client-side MVC like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/zaHc7/

**Edited for clarification of answer**

Comment: Although it may be best practice for clean looking code and efficiency... your item #1 does not matter to the issue nor does that cause any problems.  Your item #2 also does not matter or cause any problems.  It's not a relevant answer at all.

Comment: It was my attempt to answer part of the question: "I have a lot of jQuery here and I don't know how to isolate all the plugins that I'm using." from there it might be easier to debug the code.

Comment: It might be best to mention that within your answer to avoid down-votes.  As it stands it looks like you're saying more than one `document.ready` or putting code within the page will actually cause problems.